# JMeter Ultimate Thread Group to Finish all samplers in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

If my understanding of the Ultimate Thread Group plugin code is correct, all threads are scheduled at the beginning of a test with a start time and end time based on ramp up, hold load and cooldown.[(code)](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/6ab593dc32214777afa7cf4127973b528cd4bd7f/plugins/casutg/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/threads/UltimateThreadGroup.java#L65C21-L66)

However, when a thread is scheduled to end, it just receives a [shutdown signal](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/91d8aea7c42b10c68767e2f0a2a955389477f03f/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.java#L239C1-L245) and the thread does not complete (all the samplers in an iteration of the thread did not run).

In my use case, I need all samplers to be allowed to complete. For example:

1. [Sampler1] Start Call
2. [Sampler2] Speak
3. [Sampler3] DTMF
4. [Sampler4] End Call

From what I've seen, many threads will simple just stop anywhere in this sequence because that is when they were scheduled to stop. So my server won't receive an end call request for those thread iterations.

I have played around with tearDown threads but with 20K+ scenarios (calls in this case), it does not seem feasible to collect data for all calls that never ended and tear them down.

Any suggestions on how Ultimate Thread Group can be modified to achieve these results?

TL;DR: Need a solution where Ultimate Thread Group allows all samplers within a thread iteration to finish even if thread was scheduled to shutdown early.

1. I have tried tearDown thread groups but my scenarios seem to complicated to implement this
2. I have tried building a custom Ultimate Thread Group, but it does not seem much can be done since a JMeterThread is scheduled within simple a start time and end time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "modify" anything to "achieve these results".

Just put your requests under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < your-desired-test-duration-here,)}
```

This way you will get confidence that all the Samplers from your transaction will be executed before a thread is shut down.

Comment: As I mentioned in the google discussion, this is not a viable solution when dealing with Ultimate Thread Group plugin. Once a thread is scheduled to be stopped it will shutdown. No while loop will prevent the thread from shutting down.

Comment: What prevents you from modifying the "schedule" in the Ultimate Thread Group and increasing thread lifetime to some maximum value and control the test duration using the While Controller?